# Examples: (Symmetric) Quotients of Euclidean Space

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, symmetric-spaces

What are some examples of $n$-dimensional topological manifolds $M$ (possibly with boundary), which can be written as a quotient $\mathbb{R}^d/G$ for some topological group acting on $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Assuming that by Lie algebra you mean a Lie group, your M will have to be a single point.

Comment: Only if the action is transitive

Comment: Now, with the edit, this is a totally different question. In particular, it now has nothing to do with symmetric spaces. What examples of manifolds do you know which satisfy this property? It is not unreasonable to conjecture that every connected manifold can be realized this way.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: all connected manifolds can be realized as $\mathbb{R}^d/G$ really?

Comment: @C.F.G: This holds for all connected surfaces and all compact connected 3-manifolds. In higher dimensions, I am not sure, but I see no obstructions.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Interesting!! where can I read about it? ~~~~~~~ i thought that $\mathbb{R}^d/G$ is the definition of homogeneous space if discrete Lie group $G$ act freely, properly discontinuously, but you say "it now has nothing to do with symmetric spaces"!!

Comment: @C.F.G: I will write an answer in a few days. As for homogeneous spaces, the standard definition is that it is a Riemannian manifold with transitive isometry group. (Some authors allow for quotients of Lie groups by closed subgroups, without fixing a metric in advance.) A locally homogenous space is a Riemannian manifold locally isometric to a homogeneous space. This is very different from a manifold homeomorphic to the quotient of $R^n$ by a (proper) topological group action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will interpret your question as asking about manifolds which are quotients of $R^d$ by **proper** continuous actions of topological groups.

First of all, if $M$ is a connected manifold and $p: \tilde M\to M$ is the universal covering then the discrete group $G=\pi_1(M)$ acts properly on $\tilde M$ by deck-transformations of $p$ so that $M= \tilde M/G$.

Thus, you obtain some easy examples: Manifolds whose universal  cover is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^d$, e.g. tori $T^d$. Also, if $S$ is a connected surface not homeomorphic to $S^2$ or ${\mathbb R} P^2$, then the universal cover of $S$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^2$: Once can derive this from the [Uniformization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem).  This gives you more examples by taking products of surfaces and circles. With a bit more work, you also prove that if 
$$
F\to M\to B
$$
is a fiber bundle, where the fiber and base ($F$ and $B$) have universal covers homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^k, {\mathbb R}^n$ respectively, then the universal cover $\tilde M$ of $M$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^{n+k}$: This is because  the fiber bundle above lifts to a fiber bundle of universal covers:
$$
\tilde F\to \tilde M\to \tilde B
$$
and the latter is trivial since $\tilde B$ is contractible.

**Conjecture.** Every connected topological manifold $M^m$ (possibly with boundary) is homeomorphic to the quotient of some ${\mathbb R}^d$ ($d=m$ or $d=m+1$) by a proper continuous group action of a topological group.

I will prove this conjecture (when $d=m$) in the case of (arbitrary) surfaces and compact 3-manifolds ($m=3$). There is a strategy for proving the conjecture in higher dimensions, assuming that $M$ is compact and triangulated (the proof I have in mind may need $m+1$ instead of $m$ and a nondiscrete topological group $G$). I am not sure about topological manifolds.

Proof. In order to keep the discussion reasonably short, I will assume that $\partial M=\emptyset$.

If $M$ is a noncompact surface (without boundary), the universal cover of $M$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^2$ and we are done. The same for closed (compact, with empty boundary) surfaces different from $S^2$ and ${\mathbb R} P^2$.

To represent $S^2$ as the quotient of the plane, start with a square $Q\subset {\mathbb R}^2$ and let $\Gamma$ denote the group of Euclidean isometries generated by reflections $\tau_1,...,\tau_4$ in the consecutive edges of $Q$. Then ${\mathbb R}^2/\Gamma$ is naturally homeomorphic to $Q$ (since every $\Gamma$-orbit in ${\mathbb R}^2$ intersects $Q$ exactly once). Let $G_1< \Gamma$ denote the index 2 subgroup consisting of orientation-preserving isometries. Then ${\mathbb R}^2/G_1$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$: You see this by taking the union $D$ of $Q$ and $Q'=\tau_1(Q)$ and checking the identification pattern on the boundary of $D$ given by the rotations $\tau_1 \circ \tau_i, i=1,2,3$. The key fact to keep in mind is that while $\Gamma$ (and, hence, its subgroups) acts properly on the plane, it does not act freely on the plane, so the action of $G_1$ is not by covering transformations (the universal cover of $S^2$, of course, is not ${\mathbb R}^2$).  In order to get ${\mathbb R}P^2$ as the quotient, let $\sigma$ denote the unique reflection $\ne \tau_1$ and preserving $D$. Define the group $G_2$  generated by $G_1$ and the composition $\tau_1\circ \tau_2\circ \sigma$. The group $G_2$ contains $G_1$ as an index 2 subgroup and one verifies that $R^2/G_2$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}P^2$.

In order to understand what is really going on here, it is better to use the language of **[orbifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbifold#2-dimensional_orbifolds)**. The best reference I know is:

*Scott, Peter*, [**The geometries of 3-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/blms/15.5.401), Bull. Lond. Math. Soc. 15, 401-487 (1983). [ZBL0561.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0561.57001).

What I am using is that both $S^2$ and ${\mathbb R}P^2$ appear as underlying spaces or parabolic (Euclidean) orbifolds: For $S^2$ I am placing four elliptic points of order 2 on the sphere and for ${\mathbb R}P^2$ I am placing two elliptic/cone  points of order 2 on ${\mathbb R}P^2$. This creates, respectively, parabolic orbifolds ${\mathcal O}_1$ and ${\mathcal O}_2$ with respective fundamental groups isomorphic to $G_1, G_2$: The Euclidean plane on which $G_1, G_2$ are acting serves as the universal covering space (in the orbifold sense!) of both orbifolds. The groups $G_1, G_2$ are acting   on the plane as the groups of covering transformations (again, in the orbifolds sense!), hence, fixed points are allowed (and even required). I could have used different parabolic or even hyperbolic orbifold structures with the underlying spaces $S^2$ and ${\mathbb R}P^2$ to the same effect. In the latter case, the universal covering space (as a metric space) would be the hyperbolic plane.

The latter generalizes to dimension 3. I will use a theorem mostly due to Thurston:

**Theorem.** Let $M$ be a closed oriented connected 3-manifold. Then there exists a link (even a knot) $L\subset M$ such that placing a suitable orbifold data at $L$, one obtains a hyperbolic orbifold ${\mathcal O}$ with the underlying space $M$ and the singular locus $L$.

You can find proofs for instance in

*Myers, Robert*, [**Simple knots in compact, orientable 3-manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1999193), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 273, 75-91 (1982). [ZBL0508.57008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0508.57008).

*Brooks, Robert*, [**A construction of metrics of negative Ricci curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214442634), J. Differ. Geom. 29, No. 1, 85-94 (1989). [ZBL0628.53043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0628.53043).

The proof in the second paper has a chance to generalize in higher dimensions, but one needs to weaken *negative curvature* to *nonpositive curvature* (in suitable sense).

The result also holds for compact manifolds with boundary (one needs to put suitable "boundary reflectors" on $\partial M$) and non-orientable 3-manifolds.

Now, given this, let $G=\pi_1({\mathcal O})$ be the orbifold-fundamental group of ${\mathcal O}$. The property that    ${\mathcal O}$ is hyperbolic means that $G$ acts isometrically and properly on the hyperbolic 3-space ${\mathbb H}^3$ so that the quotient-orbifold ${\mathbb H}^3/G$ is isomorphic (as an orbifold) to ${\mathcal O}$. In particular, this quotient, regarded as a topological space, is homeomorphic to $M$.